# Android/Phonegap navigator.contacts.list(...) finds a contact that doesn't exist

Tags: android, cordova

Where does Phonegap/Android search for contacts more than in the contacts list?

I just played around with Phonegap on my Android phone (Samsung galaxy s2 if that makes a difference) and when calling navigator.contacts.list I got a contact that isn't in my contacts list.

I know the contact and have him on chat and whatnot but not in the contacts list.  I double checked with google contacts online and made sure they where synced and didn't find him there either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android aggregates contacts from multiple sources including chat. Read more [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/contacts.html).

Comment: Project idea: an app to administer all those contacts from all those places.  (like the email address that pops up with the rwong spelling or the other email adress that is not used any more but refuses to get deleted)